# javafx how to copy a buttons image to another in runtime?

Tags: java, button, javafx

I'm trying to copy a button's image(what ever it is) to another button, depending on some conditions.
I am using getGraphic() but whith no sucess. Can anyone help me?

Comment: The graphic is a Node and a Node can only be added once in a scene graph. So you have to create a second graphic to set to the other button.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I realise that i have to create another graphic, but my question is can i create another by copying from the first one?

Comment: No you can't simply copy it, because there is reference identity. Maybe this will help you to understand: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/user-interface-tutorial/button.htm#CJHEEACB

Answer (score 0):

I will use CSS class. First set styleSheet for javaFX app:
(https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/user-interface-tutorial/apply-css.htm#CHDGHCDG)

Then add class to styleSheet:

```
.imageButton {
    -fx-graphic: url("@../icons/document_32.png");
}
```

Add style class to button and button have image.

```
// Create button
Button btn = new Button("New Document");

// This command add style to button...
btn.getStyleClass().add("imageButton");

// Remove style and image
btn.getStyleClass().remove("imageButton");
```

Comment: Hi, your solution looks good, but i don't have the "imageButton". I need to extract it from anothe button. Is it possible?

Comment: If you work with HTML and CSS you will see this is good solution. Class names you create. For ok button class name okButton, for cancel button class name cancelButton ... Then when you change image, change only path to image in one place (css file) and all buttons who have that class have new image. Simple. CSS and HTML (FXML) is very good for styling application too, not only buttons.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bad solution, but I can't understand why you need it. It's much simpler to set the graphic directly with the image you already have.

But here it is, it assumes that you have an Icon file called ok.png in your package where the class is, like the picture below.

[image: Structure]

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class JavaFXApplication1 extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        // create an image, an image is not a Node!
        Image imageOk = new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("ok.png"));
        // create a new Button
        Button sourceBtn = new Button("Ok", new ImageView(imageOk));
        // get the buttons graphic
        Node node = sourceBtn.getGraphic();
        // you have to cast the node to an ImageView
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) node;
        // from the ImageView you are able to get the Image
        Image imageCopy = imageView.getImage();
        // a new Button instance
        Button destBtn = new Button("I'am OK, too");

        // now set the new graphic the same as the other button
        sourceBtn.setOnAction((action) -> {
            destBtn.setGraphic(new ImageView(imageCopy));
        });

        VBox root = new VBox(10.0);
        root.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        root.getChildren().addAll(sourceBtn, destBtn);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 350, 300);

        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

The application will look like this initial

[image: Initial]

and after clicked the image button:

[image: After]

Comment: Hi NwDx,thats exactly what i needed. Cant understand why tou call it a bad solution. This is for a situation where i have like 30 buttons each one with a diferent image, and, after the user select one, i want to copy it's image to another colled the 'selected one'. So this, i think, is a good solution. Thank you vary much.

Comment: @asfourhund You're welcome! I called it bad, because of the needed class cast from Node to ImageView, but in your situtation this is maybe the least problem :-)